# The 1st controller in the UINavigationController should appear, by default, when launching the app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Am a newbie to App development. I created a Navigation Controller template project and added few pages to it. It looks like below:

[image]

**MY QUESTION**
When the App launches, I want the 'Home' page (which is the first ViewController in the list) to be shown by default. And then, if the users want to get to this Menu screen (i.e. the list of controllers), they need to be able to press the 'Back' button (which would appear in the top navigation bar).

**WHAT I TRIED OUT**
I tried this by pulling the '--->' arrow mark (which now points to the Navigation controller) to the ViewController that represents the 'Home' screen. As expected, when I ran the app, the page representing the 'Home' screen was shown first. However, the 'Back' button was missing in the Navigation Bar (it's obvious why, though) and so one cannot goto the Menu page.

Can someone please pour in your expertise!

Thanks,
Jean

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method below in `viewDidAppear:animated` method

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:) withObject:@"MainRootView" afterDelay:2.0f];
```

here `@"MainRootView"` is identifier defined in storyboard in segue, used to call or load the view and the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method is as follow

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Segue about to be performed");
}
```

this will load the view who's segue identifier is `@"MainRootView"`.

May this help you.

Happy Coding :)